# Are pipelines capable of cacheing intermediate results?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

I use pandas to do feature extraction for machine learning.
I hope to achieve the following: Consider I have five data processing steps done sequentially, and I execute thme once. Eesults will be saved automatically. Next time, if I change the fourth step, the library will automatically start from the third step.

Would this cache function be supported in Pandas or `sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline` or other data processing libraries naturally without our need to save them explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

[MLFlow Tracking](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/tracking.html) has some nice features that seem to be lacking in Dagster (a record of the current git commit, ML metrics, etc.) They also integrate nicely with [Databricks](https://databricks.com/product/managed-mlflow) that allows for easy cluster deployment. However, they really lack in building complicated pipelines, in which Dagster excels.

Is there a way to get "the best of all worlds"? That is, integrate Dagster with MLFlow and have it thus run on Databricks?

Or is there a good alternative?

Comment: Moomima, have you found a way to integrate Dagster and MLFlow? I am also interested in seeing these two tools combined.

Answer (score 0):

VevestaX (https://github.com/Vevesta/VevestaX) can be used to track features and parameters used in the Machine learning experiment. It can be installed with

```
pip install vevestaX
```

Has easy commands to track features used. Example:

```
V.dataSourcing = df
```

In a jupyter notebook, this command would need to be run once and it will capture the features. Or to capture feature engineering, you just need to run the following command

```
V.featureEngineering = df
```

or

```
V.fe = df
```

Lastly the variables can be captured by writing it between the code block V.start() and V.end()

```
V.start()
epochs = 10
V.end()
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30478720)

Comment: Explained the answer more. Thanks for the inputs